# IntegrityError inside model.DoesNotExist exception in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I try to save webpages to database, the url should be unique. If the url is already exist, i just need to create relation between Webpage class and searching class. But the problem is, i keep getting this IntegrityError even if the database is empty and the operation is happens inside DoesNotExist exception. Please help me solve my problem.

Here is the chunk views.py code that do the saving.

```
websearch.startSearch(maxPage=2)
    for result in websearch.searchResult:
        try:
            web = Webpage.objects.get(url=result)
            searching.objects.create(webpage=web, keyword=keyword)
        except Webpage.DoesNotExist:
            web = Webpage.objects.create(url=result)
            searching.objects.create(webpage=web, keyword=keyword)
```

Here is the Webpage & searching model

```
class Webpage(models.Model) :
    "webpage from search result and client's websites"
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, blank=True, null=True)
    webhosting = models.ForeignKey(WebHosting, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=False, unique=True)
    html_page = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    inspect_status = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    scam_status =  models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    report_status =  models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    access_status =  models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    whitelist_status =  models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    compare_to = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

class searching (models.Model):
    'information on each searching activity'
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, blank=True, null=True)
    token = models.ForeignKey(Token, blank=True, null=True)
    webpages = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
class comparison(models.Model):
    '''comparing website to other websites with the same event and label'''
    source = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, related_name='compare_source')
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, related_name='compare_destination')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    fuzz_ratio = models.FloatField()
    fuzz_partial_ratio = models.FloatField()
    fuzz_token_sort_ratio = models.FloatField()
    fuzz_token_set_ratio =  models.FloatField()
    difflib_ratio =  models.FloatField()
    difflib_quick_ratio =  models.FloatField()
    difflib_real_quick_ratio =  models.FloatField()
    levenshtein_ratio =  models.FloatField()
    levenshtein_seqratio =  models.FloatField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the IntegrityError is not cause by url field in the Webpage model as i thought.  It is in the BooleanField type field. I changed the Webpage model to this:

```
class Webpage(models.Model):
    "webpage from search result and client's websites"
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, blank=True, null=True)
    webhosting = models.ForeignKey(WebHosting, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=False)
    html_page = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    text_body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    inspect_status = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    scam_status =  models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    report_status =  models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    access_status =  models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    whitelist_status =  models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    compare_to = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.url
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to handle exceptions, you can use `get_or_create` built in function.

```
websearch.startSearch(maxPage=2)
    for result in websearch.searchResult:

         webpage, created = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(url=result)
         #webpage is a instance 
         #created is True is a new instance was created or False if it already existed.
```

Also, you have a typo

```
searching.objects.create(webpage=web, keyword=keyword)
```

should be

```
searching.objects.create(webpages=web, keyword=keyword)
```

`Searching` object has `webpages` attribute not webpage, you need to add a `'s'`

Comment: @pupil  I updated it, you have a typo, you forgot 's' in webpage attribute on  `searching.objects.create(webpage=web, keyword=keyword)`

Comment: After fix the typo, i still get the error. The debuging page shows the error is in the creation of Webpage object. I tried creating Webpage object from shell but still get the same error. I still can't fix it.